# How do I create a file on internal storage that can then be read through the computer?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create an android application that writes to a text file that can later be accessed once a button is pushed.

The past week i've tried a bunch of methods that people suggest to write to the internal storage, and sometimes it appears to work (using an outputwriter, and also a File class?), but i'm never able to locate the file on the Android device I test-run it on.

I'm rather new to development for Android, so all this is confusing to me.

Thanks

Comment: On your device's internal storage, locate the folder called `Android/data/<your-project-package-name>/` - you should find the file there.

Comment: *internal* storage is private to your application. On some devices you can't even see those files / folders unless the device is rooted. Maybe try it with external storage, which is publicly accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "internal storage" you mean what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), this is not possible. Files that you create there are only accessible to your app, not by file managers on or off the device.

If by "internal storage", you mean what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), you need to:

- Get a `File` pointing to a directory on external storage, such as calling `getExternalFilesDir()` on some `Context`, like your `Activity`
- Create that directory if it does not exist
- Create a `File` object pointing to the file you want to create, off of that directory
- Use standard Java file I/O to write to the location identified by that `File`
- Use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to tell Android "hey, I just put a file on external storage, please index it so it shows up in file managers"

Also:

- Ideally, you do the disk I/O on a background thread, so you do not freeze the UI while that work is going on.
- Depending on your `minSdkVersion` and where you choose to write the file, you may need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission
- Depending on your `targetSdkVersion`, you may need to ask for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You CAN access internal storage sometimes, but this depends on your phone.

1. You always can get data from internal memory for rooted phones (need root).
   Files are in the folder /Android/data/
2. Some vendors allows you to run root shell on non-rooted phone through adb
   (I saw this behaviour on Explay tabet) just run `adb shell su` to
   test. Then you can copy your file from internal storage to public
   with shell commands.
3. adb pull may also work in this case. (Again
   vendor dependent)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification